# Setting an Illustrator file to 120ppi

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, cmyk, ppi

So I need to make some panels for one of those 4-panel stand-up [convention displays](http://www.exhibitors-handbook.com/Includes/DownloadFile.aspx?name=GraphicTemplates/pdf/folding-display-panels/hero/Hero_H08_template.pdf) and the template specs they gave me are clear about the bleed/trim and basic stuff, but it says "Resolution must be 100-120ppi" which has me confused.

My question is, where can I set it to 120ppi in Illustrator since the only raster effects options I see available are for 300, 150, and 72ppi? Also personally I've never done anything below 150, I thought that at sizes of like 76"x12.7"+ at below 150 you're not really getting as much bang for your buck resolution wise.

So hoping someone can set me straight. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Illustrator is a vector illustration tool. Vector files are resolution agnostic--meaning a ppi resolution is irrelevant in this case.

Send them the .ai files or a PDF created from the .ai file and that should be fine.

If you are using raster effects, then set them to 150. No harm in going a bit higher than the spec.

Remember that large format printing doesn't typically need a high resolution as people are looking at it from a distance.

Vendors typically have specs like this to avoid the typical "person sends a word file with a few GIFs pasted form the web" annoyances.

Comment: +1 but a comment its not actually true that theres no harm for over resolution but in this case its pretty harmless, yes.

Comment: Excellent thanks, ya it will be a mix of vector and raster